# What down implies when used as a preposition in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

I somewhere found this sentence:

"They set off at a jog up one street and down another."
 Is this sentence correct since I feel here "at" should be replaced with "for" ?And what exactly they tried to imply by saying"up one street and down another"??I have made a rough guess but failed to picturize it completely.Can someone explain the meaning of this sentence??

Answer (score 1):

(1) We use 'at' to describe the speed of something - People can move at a slow pace, at a jog, at a run, at a furious pace. These people ran at a jog. He drove at 60 kph. (2) 'Up' and 'down' are to be considered relatively. They ran along one street in a certain direction, and then moved to another (presumably adjacent) street and ran along it in the opposite direction (probably arriving not too far from their starting point). Up and down are opposites, as I expect you already know. In constructions of this kind, 'up' is usually first, and 'down' second.

Answer (score 0):

In the US, at least (not sure about the UK), "up" and "down" are frequently used as directions on a street.  The terms are a little vague such that, absent an obvious hill, "up" will often mean simply "in a direction away from this point", though in a particular town "down" may refer to the business district and "up" to the residential district.  Or "up" may refer to a higher-priced neighborhood -- like I said, it depends on the town.

Comment: Just the same in the UK.